# Why we can't get as fast internet speed as NASA?

Tags: networking

Some months ago I came to know that [NASA](https://www.voanews.com/silicon-valley-technology/nasa-breaks-data-transmission-speed-record-laser-shot-moon) has the fastest internet on the planet (with obvious reasons). But, my point is not that

> • I want to know why we commoners can't have such speed in our households, is that because it's very much costly with current technology.
> •Can anyone focus on the future of such internet planning and the perspective of it's reality.

Comment: That article clearly states that the communication was not IP.  It is not the internet, it is a point-to-point link.  Secondly, the speed quoted is less than half the speed achieved elsewhere - https://www.totaltele.com/506827/UK-scientists-build-ultra-broadband-delivering-178-terabits-per-second

Comment: Please read the [introduction](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/) to the IoT Stack Exchange site. This question has nothing to do with IoT and as such is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The article is not about an Internet connection, but about a point-to-point link to a probe on the moon.

They achieved a speed of 622 Mbit/s, which is the speed achieved in an STM-4 SDH link, something that existed 20 years ago here on Earth.

Back then, it was something you would see mostly on ISP backbones, but nowadays you’ll see FTTH (fibre to the home) Internet connections running at 1 Gbit/s and more.

I currently have a 400 Mbit/s connection at home (Docsis over coax). They just connected fibre to my building, which will give me access to at least 2 Gbit/s connections. Of course, either is much higher than what you can achieve over xDSL (ADSL up to about 20 Mbit/s or VDSL up to 100 Mbit/s or so). It’s just a matter of medium. There’s only so much you can transmit over decades-old thin, not twisted, not shielded telephone wiring. If you want more, fibre is a much better option.

Note that even wireless links (5G) can achieve more than that. The difficulty in their test is the distance (and probably also the relative movement).

Comment: Your answer didn't focus on the part of reality and stuffs I wanted. But isn't bad.

Comment: @S.MUKHERJEE I'm not sure I understand your comment. You were asking why we can't get such speeds, and I'm telling you that in many cases we can actually get even better speeds than those described in that article, as long as we can get fibre to the home/building/premises (FTTH, FTTB, FTTP). If you can't get fibre to the premises, then you are limited by the speeds reachable using xDSL technologies. And the the reason you can't get better speeds in those cases is indeed just a matter of cost.